# Haskell type families and dummy arguments

Tags: haskell, type-families

I made a function similar to numpy's `array`. It converts lists to arrays, lists of lists to 2d arrays, etc.

It works like this:

```
ghci> arrFromNestedLists ["hello", "world"] :: Array (Int, (Int, ())) Char
array ((0,(0,())),(1,(4,()))) [((0,(0,())),'h'),((0,(1,())),'e'),((0,(2,())),'l'),((0,(3,())),'l'),((0,(4,())),'o'),((1,(0,())),'w'),((1,(1,())),'o'),((1,(2,())),'r'),((1,(3,())),'l'),((1,(4,())),'d')]
```

`(Int, (Int, ()))` and not `(Int, Int)` because I don't know of a programatic way to increase the length of a tuple. (side question: is there such way?)

The coding of it was awkward and I had to do a "workaround" (passing around dummy arguments to functions) for it to work. I wonder if there's a better way.

So here's the code, interrupted with details of the ugly workarounds:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeFamilies #-}

type family ListOfIndex i a
type instance ListOfIndex () a = a
type instance ListOfIndex (Int, i) a = [ListOfIndex i a]

class Ix i => ArrConv i where
  acBounds :: a -> ListOfIndex i a -> (i, i)
  acFlatten :: i -> ListOfIndex i a -> [a]
```

`acBounds` "should" be `:: ListOfIndex i a -> (i, i)`. And similarly for `acFlatten`. Each is given a dummy variable (`undefined` is always the value given) because otherwise I couldn't get it to compile :(

```
arrFromNestedLists :: forall i a. ArrConv i => ListOfIndex i a -> Array i a
arrFromNestedLists lst =
  listArray
  (acBounds (undefined :: a) lst)
  (acFlatten (undefined :: i) lst)
```

Above is the dummy `undefined` argument passing at work. It tells the GHC which instance of `ListOfIndex` to use.

```
instance ArrConv () where
  acBounds _ = const ((), ())
  acFlatten _ = (: [])
```

The below function should have been the `acBounds` function in an instance of `ArrConv`, and is declared outside only because I need to use `ScopedTypeVariables` and I don't know how I can do it in a function in an instance definition..

```
acSucBounds
  :: forall a i. ArrConv i
  => a -> [ListOfIndex i a] -> ((Int, i), (Int, i))
acSucBounds _ lst =
  ((0, inStart), (length lst - 1, inEnd))
  where
    (inStart, inEnd) = acBounds (undefined :: a) (head lst)

instance ArrConv i => ArrConv (Int, i) where
  acBounds = acSucBounds
  acFlatten _ = concatMap (acFlatten (undefined :: i))
```

Comment: "I don't know of a programmatic way to increase the length of a tuple." I don't think you can. That's a perfect example of a function whose type depends on a value. It would be easy to do in a dependently typed language like `Agda`, but impossible in Haskell. Maybe you could use `GADTs` in some way to give you some dependent behavior, but off the top of my head, I don't know how.

Comment: Maybe Template Haskell can be useful: http://www.haskell.org/bz/thdoc.htm   http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell

Comment: @primodemus: With TH I could make instances for `ArrConv` for arrays of up to 10 dimensions, and they would be using normal tuples for indexes, which is an improvement. But I would feel like the limit is arbitrary and the code is probably going to be much less readable.

Comment: Looking at your original example, how is the compiler supposed to know whether you want `Array (Int, (Int, ()) Char` or `Array (Int, ()) String` ? My suspicion is that the inherent ambiguity of your problem is what leads to the need to pass the dummy arguments to fix the type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that the extra arguments to acBounds and acFlatten are necessary is that the types `a` and `i` cannot be recovered from `ListOfIndex i a -> (i, i)` and `ListOfIndex i a -> [a]` respectively.  One workaround is to combine the two methods into one method `acArgs` of type `ListOfIndex i a -> ((i, i), a)`.  Now the only problem is to use it in the instance of `(Int, i)` in a way which prevents the typechecker from generalizing its type too much causing the same problem as before (for example, we cannot simply use `fst . acArgs`).

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Array

type family ListOfIndex i a
type instance ListOfIndex () a = a
type instance ListOfIndex (Int, i) a = [ListOfIndex i a]

class Ix i => ArrConv i where
  acArgs :: ListOfIndex i a -> ((i, i), [a])

instance ArrConv () where
  acArgs x = (((), ()), [x])

instance ArrConv i => ArrConv (Int, i) where
  acArgs lst =
    (((0, inStart), (length lst - 1, inEnd)), args >>= snd)
    where
      args = map acArgs lst
      (inStart, inEnd) = fst (head args)

arrFromNestedLists :: ArrConv i => ListOfIndex i a -> Array i a
arrFromNestedLists = uncurry listArray . acArgs
```

Comment: @Reid Barton: Awesome! Thanks :) I refactored your answer a little (I hope you don't mind): Instead of passing `acArgs` to a function make it monomorphic, it now only uses it in one place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep `acBounds` and `acFlatten` separate, you could add a [type-level tag argument](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/tagged/0.4.2.1/doc/html/Data-Proxy.html) to it, i.e. `acBounds` would have type `acBounds :: Proxy a -> ListOfIndex i a -> (i, i)`. This removes the need for the `undefined` arguments, since you can just pass `(Proxy :: SomeConcreteType)` to it; and `acBounds` has no way of extracting any useful value-level information from it, since it is isomorphic (in an untyped way) to the unit type.